# how do I correctly add to an item of a list to a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am struggling to correctly add the list of the elements to the while statement below.
I have a pre-defined list of elements which include the days the snail climbed each day.
With the below code I am trying to create a while loop with the list, however, it seems to be incorrect.
snail escapes the well
"""
A snail falls at the bottom of a '125' cm well.
Each day the snail rises 30 cm.
But at night, while sleeping, slides 20 cm because the walls are wet.
How many days does it take for the snail to escape the well?
Hint: The snail gets out of the well when it surpasses the 125cm of height.
"""

'''
Loop: while
Conditional statements: if-else
Function: print()
'''

'''
Assign the challenge data to variables with representative names:
well_height,
daily_distance,
nightly_distance and snail_position.
'''
advance_cm = [30, 21, 33, 77, 44, 45, 23, 45, 12, 34, 55]
'''
Bonus
The distance traveled by the snail each day is now defined by a list.
'''

```
well_height = 125
# daily_distance = 30
nightly_distance = 20
snail_position = 0
notEscaped = True


# Create a variable days to keep
# count of the days that pass until the snail escapes the well

days = 0

fullDaylydist = advance_cm[0] - nightly_distance

while snail_position < well_height:
    if days == 1:
        print(str(days) + " day gone")
    else:
        print(str(days) + " days gone")
    snail_position += advance_cm[days]
    if snail_position < well_height:
        snail_position -= nightly_distance  # The snail slides down the well here
        days += 1
# Print the solution.
    else:
        print(str(days) + " days and I am out from the well!")
        #  What is its maximum displacement in one day?
        print(str(max(advance_cm)) + " cm is the maximum distance the snail climbed in one day")
        #  And its minimum?
        #  Calculate the displacement using only the travel distance of the days used to get out of the well.
        print(str(min(advance_cm)) + " cm is the minimum distance the snail climbed in one day")
        # What is its average progress? Take into account the snail slides at night.
        # average_progress = (sum(days) * range(advance_cm)) - (sum(days) * nightly_distance)
        advSum = sum(advance_cm)
        advCnt = len(advance_cm)
        avgSpd = advSum / advCnt
        print(avgSpd)  # What is its average speed during the day?
        _stdDev = [(x - avgSpd) ** 2 for x in advance_cm]
        # What is the standard deviation of its displacement during the day?
        print(_stdDev)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only ever using the first value from `advance_cm`, as each time you reference it you're just doing `advance_cm[0]`. You also are not using `nightly_distance` in the loop, meaning the snail is never sliding back down the well. The loop should look like this:

```
while snail_position < well_height:
    if days == 1: # In yours, it would say "0 day gone", small correction
        print(str(days) + " day gone")
    else:
        print(str(days) + " days gone")
    snail_position += advance_cm[days] # Now it will use a different distance each day
    if snail_position < well_height:
        snail_postition -= nightly_distance # The snail slides down the well here
        days += 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly!

One last question, could you explain to me with the standard deviation calculation?

Comment: I'm not going to do all your work for you, but there's a quick and easy explanation of standard deviation here: https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html

A couple quick tips: you can use the built-in sum() and a list comprehension to easily handle the standard deviation. You can read about list comprehensions here: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Comment: Thank you!
I actually came up with this and it seems to be logically correct, however, the standard deviation is now calculated for the full length of [advanced_cm] instead of the days it took the snail to escape.

advSum = sum(advance_cm)
        advCnt = len(advance_cm)
        avgSpd = advSum / advCnt
        print(avgSpd)  # What is its average speed during the day?
        _stdDev = [(x - avgSpd) ** 2 for x in advance_cm]
        # What is the standard deviation of its displacement during the day?
        print(_stdDev)

Comment: You know how many days it's been, as you get that from the while-loop. You can use that number to get a slice of the list. You can do that with ```days_travelled = advance_cm[:(days+1)]```. The +1 is because days only gets incremented in the loop when the snail doesn't get out.